# Is it a good nginx config?

Tags: php, redirect, nginx, webserver, http-status-code-301

Is it a good nginx config? And did i used 301 redirects right (i have multiple domains and want all of them to point to https://domain.ru), and didn't i screwed up all of my future seo with them? It's gonna be server for 1-2 wordpress sites with nginx, percona and php-fpm

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://domain.ru$request_uri;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com домен-домен.рф www.домен-домен.рф домен.рф www.домен.рф www.domain.ru domain.ru;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/12345.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/12345.key;
    server_name www.domain.ru;
    return 301 https://domain.ru$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/12345.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/12345.key;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain.ru;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

        location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
                expires max;
    }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about cyrillic domain names. Probably you should use puny-code like `xn----gtbbcc2bdfecf.xn--p1ai` for `домен-домен.рф`. Also no need for `ssl on` directive. Otherwise it's pretty standard config

Comment: it works well with cyrillc domain names, or is there any other reason to use punycode? and did i get it right, i need `ssl on;` directive only if i use  `listen 443 ssl;` and `listen 80;` in one server block? @AlexeyTen

Comment: How did you check? I don't see any punycode support in nginx's sources.

Comment: http://кубок-огня.рф @AlexeyTen

Comment: You don't need `ssl on` in anycase. It's obsolete and replaced by `ssl` flag in listen directive for ages.

Comment: If it's the only block that listen to port 80, then `кубок-огня.рф` just falls into it as default server block, not because nginx choose it by server name. Just test with two separate server block with different configs.

Comment: thank you @AlexeyTen ! and do you know, will using redirects like this affect seo in any way?

Comment: SEO is not my area of expertise.

Comment: thank you very much! replaced with punycodes and now it works great! thanks!! @AlexeyTen